# Calling a function in mylibray onclick passing this

Tags: javascript, function, this

I've got this onclick call that works.

```
<ul id="ul_name" onclick="javascript:mylibrary.ul_action(this);">
```

I don't want to manually add the call on every ul so i tried this one:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var u = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass ul");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
   u[i].onclick = mylibrary.ul_action(this);
   };
};
```

But it doesn't work. It's this's scope wrong? Or what? Thank you.

Comment: pass id  in params ans use that id in click function to get desired element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function **immediately** and assigning the *return value* as your `click` event handler.

You need to create a new function that calls your existing function with the argument you want (which **isn't** `this` because you want it to be the element):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var mylibrary = {
    ul_action: function(ul) {
      console.log(ul.innerText);
    }
  };

  var u = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass ul");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
    u[i].onclick = mylibrary.ul_action.bind(window, u[i]);
  };
};
```

```html
<main class="myclass">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: @Sugnasugna — Works in the live demo in my answer.

Comment: I think I have an environment issue. If I load mylibrary on window.onload neither of two metods work.